# GGPLOT2: Stacked bar plot for two discrete variable columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

I have a dataset with three columns (one categorical column and two-discrete variables column). I want to make a stacked bar plot to compare the values of the two discrete variables for each category. However, I get continuous coloring rather than discrete colors.

Reproducible code

```
sampleData <-  data.frame(grp = c("A","B", "C"),
                          var_1 = c(15,20, 25),
                          var_2 = c(12, 13, 20))
sampleData

p <- ggplot(sampleData, aes(x = grp, y = var_1, fill= var_2)) +
  geom_bar( stat="identity", position = "fill")+
  coord_flip()+ theme_bw()
p
```

[image: Output from above code]

Instead, what I want is

[image: Expected output]

**Var2* will always be smaller than its corresponding *Var1* value for a particular *category*.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that you haven't fixed your tibble from Wide to Long.

```
FixedData <- sampleData %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("var_1", "var_2"), names_prefix = "var_", 
               names_to = "Variable Number", values_to = "ValueName")
```

Once you do this, the problem becomes much easier to solve. You only need to change a few things, most notably the `y`, `fill`, and `position` variables to make it work.

```
p2 <- ggplot(FixedData, aes(x = grp, y = ValueName, fill = `Variable Number`)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "stack")+
  coord_flip()+ theme_bw()

p2
```